# Using WLAN and LAN in parallel for Web and Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, lan, windows-networking

There are multiple similar questions already on SU but they seem to refer to increasing the bandwidth by using LAN and WLAN in parallel.

What I would like to do on Windows 7 is using WLAN for surfing and LAN for Remote Desktop in parallel. Currently I have to deactivate WLAN for using RD on LAN. The optimal solution of course would be to simply surf via LAN - sadly this is not possible.

Is it possible to configure which network access is used by what programs?

Comment: I fail to see the purpose of your question. Could you elaborate more? By default, Windows works with priorities over cards (or master and slave if you prefer) and will prefer a certain device. If one fails, the other one will take over the traffic. And if your device is connected with ethernet AND wifi, why would you prefer to use wifi for surfing? Let everything go over your ethernet cable.

Comment: I can only surf via WLAN and use RD via LAN. And often I would like to use RD and the web in the same time. clear?

Comment: Why is that? Please give full details on how your network is set up.

Comment: You may be able to set a firewall rule to prevent the RD server from using the WLAN interface.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by one of my coworkers:

yes it's possible, you set the interface metric so that the WLAN is the preferred interface (so the Internet traffic goes out the WLAN) and then either

a) add a route for the RDSH IP that prefers the LAN interface or

b) add a firewall rule blocking MSTSC from connecting over the WLAN as suggested

Comment: I added an outgoing rule to the firewall referring to mstsc.exe blocking its access to WLAN and also specifically allowing it connecting exclusively over LAN - it does not work - do I have to consider something?